# Can anyone help using M2M and the template properly?

Tags: python, django

I need to show the name of menu and the quantity of it.

But this webpage doesn't show  even when the client's address and their name is working out right.

I've got these models(client side) in my Django project:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        Menu,
        through='OrderItem',
        through_fields=('order', 'menu'),
    )

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

and the template page like below.

```
  {% for order in order_set %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ order.client.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.address }}</td>
    <td>{% for item in order.items_set.all %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</td>
    <td>{{ order.item_set.all.count }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Models(partner side) like below.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(
    Partner,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
    verbose_name="메뉴 이미지"
    )
    name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    verbose_name="메뉴 이름"
    )
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    verbose_name="가격"
    )
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for order in order_set %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ order.client.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ order.address }}</td>
    <td>{% for item in order.items.all %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}</td>
    <td>{{ order.items.all.count }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

i.e., replace `order.items_set.all` with `order.items.all`. There is no relationship defined by `items_set`. The field you've defined on your `Order` model is `items`, so that is what you need to access.

The `FOO_set` approach is used for relationships [*in reverse*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) on things like foreign keys. In this case you're following a relationship forward.

Comment: I can access through items, as you said. And this code, {{order.items.all.count}}, works also well. Thanks a lot. But the name of menu doesn't look right. I need an actual name of menu like "Pizza". But it shows "menu object(1)" like that. I added a code for class Menu above. May you also search that code? I also tried {% for item.name in order.items.all %}, which doesn't work.